# ツイートの埋め込み用コードを自作する、について

Tags: twitter

**下記サイトに掲載されている内容を試すと期待した通り動作するのですが、なぜですか？**
[【Twitter】埋め込み処理をAPIに投げずにローカルで行う](http://mizuff.hatenablog.com/entry/twitter-oembed)

本来であれば、下記コードを掲載する必要があると思うのですが、リンク先コードだけで正常動作する理由が分かりません。

```html
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="ja"><p lang="ja" dir="ltr">『見つめて… ! もっと強く、強くです ! ムムムーン ! …曲がりませんね』<br><br>SSレアの堀裕子ちゃん登場です！<a href="https://t.co/mIoEjCBQs4">https://t.co/mIoEjCBQs4</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/%E3%83%87%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86?src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">#デレステ</a> <a href="https://t.co/Ffflbfgs4b">pic.twitter.com/Ffflbfgs4b</a></p>&mdash; スターライトステージ (@imascg_stage) <a href="https://twitter.com/imascg_stage/status/774134264107372548?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">2016年9月9日</a></blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

---

> ツイートのURL（細かく言えばscreen_nameとid）さえあればwidgets.jsがうまく処理してくれます

それなら、公式サイトでもそれだけ掲載しておけば良いと思うのですが¨

---

**追記**

・リンク先ページに掲載されていた下記「埋め込み自作コード」を試しても同じ結果が表示されました
・短く書けるなら短く書けたほうが良いと思うのですが、Twitterはなぜ上記のように長いコードを埋め込みコードとして提示するのか疑問に思い質問しました

```html
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><a href="https://twitter.com/imascg_stage/status/774134264107372548"></a></blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> それなら、公式サイトでもそれだけ掲載しておけば良いと思うのですが

[Embedded Tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-parameter-reference)で埋め込み方や、widgets.jsの提供するJavaScript関数、`blockquote`に指定できるパラメーターなどすべて説明されています。

埋め込み方の質問ではないと判断したためリンク紹介にとどめます。

---

> 短く書けるなら短く書けたほうが良いと思うのですが、Twitterはなぜ上記のように長いコードを埋め込みコードとして提示するのか

その疑問はリンク先のFAQに既に答えられています。

> ### What happens when an author deletes their Tweet?
>
> The Twitter widgets JavaScript will not display a fully-rendered Tweet if the Tweet no longer exists on Twitter. The fallback `<blockquote>` containing Tweet information will be visible on the page.

Tweetが削除されていれば表示しようがないため、埋め込んだ時点で得られていたテキストを表示する方がよいでしょう。付け加えると、SEO的にもTweetテキストに関連があるページとして検索エンジンに認識されます。

Comment: 自作するコードを使用してもよいでしょうか？

Comment: @re9 「自作する」の意味が読み取れなかったので、質問文に加筆してより具体的に説明してください。

Comment: 本文に追記しました

Comment: 見落としていました。回答読んで納得しました